# Release from pulling back with stretched hands and locked elbows

Tags: self-defense, krav-maga

Following the [video](https://www.facebook.com/100000427881320/videos/1266395243384726/) at 40 seconds. We can see man holds the little boy hands stretched to the back and pulls him back. The elbows of both hands are locked back. Is there a way to release from such situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, don't allow that position to be achieved. That particular position is not a viable attack, it will only work when the attacker has a massive size advantage (like in the video).

To get out of it:
When the arms are stretched back, the palms will either be facing in towards each other or possibly upwards. Simply rotate the palms into a pronated position (facing down), then curl your arms in (like a bicep curl) while stepping backwards - this will position you right up against your attacker. If you have bent your arms sufficiently then your wrists will be at your side or even in front of you, and the attacker will have a very tenuous grip by this stage due to the position and location of your wrists - at this point it will be trivial to break their grip and go to work on them.

This pull-forward movement is a naturally strong movement for you to make, it is hard for an attacker to resist it. Stepping back at the same time will help to destabilize their position and help to nullify a front kick they might attempt. Their only real option to continue the attack is to let go - which is exactly what you want. (Arguably they could step forward and headbutt you, but that is a risky move for them and they will also slacken their hold as they do it, which gives you an opportunity to move).